# How to "eachSeries" with Observables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, rxjs, observable

How would I implement the functionality of async's [eachSeries](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries) where you iterate over an array and manually invoke a callback to continue the iteration?

As far as I could figure out, you can iterate over an array with RxJs' Observable like [this](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/creating_and_subscribing_to_simple_observable_sequences.html):

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];

// Converts an array to an observable sequence
var source = Rx.Observable.from(array);

// Prints out each item
var subscription = source.subscribe(
  x => console.log('onNext: %s', x),
  e => console.log('onError: %s', e),
  () => console.log('onCompleted'));

// => onNext: 1
// => onNext: 2
// => onNext: 3
// => onNext: 4
// => onNext: 5
// => onCompleted
```

Here the Observable emits "automatically" each array element, but how would I tell it to continue only when I need to. Like with RxJS' Subject next() method.

In fact my real world scenario is that I need to invoke an other function inside the observer callback. With async I would pass async's callback to continue the iteration to that function and invoke it from there. But I have no clue how to do that with Observables. Are they appropriate for this case anyway? Or should I stick to async?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The entire conceptual point of Observables is to feed you data when appropriate, you don't request it. That's why you're observing, not polling.

Comment: depends on your use case, but `.concatMap` should do the job like here: http://plnkr.co/edit/6TIO9uyuzKJu59a8WwO5?p=preview.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make use of an [iterator/generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)?

It seems to be the use-case you have in mind

You could iterate it like in this example

```js
function *iterator(source) {
  let i = 0, len = source.length;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    yield source[i];
  }
}

var array = [1,2,3,4,5], iter = iterator( array );

var val = iter.next();
while (!val.done) {
  console.log(`${val.value} ( done? ${val.done} )` );
  val = iter.next();
}
console.log('done');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is very close to what you need:

```
import {Observable, Subject} from 'rxjs';

var subject = new Subject();

var interval = setInterval(_ => {
    subject.next(null);
}, 1000);

Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5])
    .concatMap(val => Observable.of(val)
        .delayWhen(_ => subject)
        .do(val => console.log('.do:', val))
    )
    .subscribe(val => console.log('next:', val), undefined, () => clearInterval(interval));
```

See live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/v77hCqOVDBqRxpWdW4Nv?p=preview

I'm using [`delayWhen()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-delayWhen) operator to be able to manually trigger emission of the next value. Then [`concatMap()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap) waits until the previous Observable returned from the callback completes so this makes the chain to be called in correct order one by one.

Note that the initial emission of `Observable.from(...)` happens immediately and each item is delayed in `concatMap()`.

This demo prints to console:

```
.do: 1
next: 1
.do: 2
next: 2
.do: 3
next: 3
.do: 4
next: 4
.do: 5
next: 5
```